# Google Maps Interactivity

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Quick scenario to describe what I'm trying to do:

Say for instance you're an airline and you want to show a map of the cities that you provide service between. So an user pulls up the displayed Google Maps and it shows you have a marker in Miami and a marker in New York. I'd like for a user to be able to click on the Miami marker and it that causes a line to animate and draws an arched arrow connecting to New York's marker or even multiple cities that would be associated to Miami.

Anyone have any idea if something like that is possible outside of accomplishing this in Flash or some way that's not native to Google Maps API?

Comment: It is definitely possible to animate a line, but I don't have a Version 3 example to cite as an answer. There is [a Version 2 example](http://econym.org.uk/gmap/example_cartrip2.htm) which uses a directions polyline but could just as easily use a geodesic line between two points (and a faster animation) as you propose.

Comment: You put me on the right path. I stumbled across this https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/geometry and it has been a good starting point so far. I tweaked the script a bit and now just trying to figure out how to get two geodesic lines to originate from one point to two other separate points on the map. I'll need a one to many display.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this one:

http://maps.forum.nu/v3/gm_flight_path_animated.html

It plots 3 animated routes: Miami - Warsaw, Miami - Cairo and Miami - Sidney.

Apologies for the somewhat disorganized code, but it is the first piece I've written since I injured one hand, so I tried to do as little typing as possible.